# Selecting multiple lines in Atom

Tags: sublimetext, atom-editor

Is there any way in Atom to replicate the feature in Sublime Text where you can hold down the <kbd>alt</kbd> key and move the mouse up or down to select and create a cursor at the end of multiple line so you can edit multiple lines simultaneously?

Comment: Are you asking if Atom has this feature? Or are you asking if it can be added via an extension?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to select multiple lines and create a cursor at the end of each line. There are a couple ways you can achieve this:

1. Using Split Into Lines

   1. Highlight multiple lines however you like.
   2. Use the `Selection|Split Into Lines` command (<kbd>Cmd+Shift+L</kbd> on OS X or press <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> and type `Split Into Lines`) to split the multiline selection into a selection for each line.
   3. Press the right arrow by itself to reveal the cursor at the end of the selections.
2. Using Add Selection Below

   1. Position the cursor on the line above the first line you want to select
   2. Use `Selection|Add Selection Below` to add as many lines with cursors as you want
   3. Use normal cursor positioning commands to place the cursors where you want

Comment: Works great, except that I can't select the beginning of every line if there are empty lines in the set. For example, I'd like to take multiple paragraphs of text, some of which has double-CR endings between paragraphs, and at a '> ' to each line. When I try to do this I get a strange selection that me the beginning of each paragraph, and the end of the last sentence of the previous-to-a-double-CR paragraph selection.

Answer (score 22):

> I am big fan of **Sublime Text 3**, **Atom** is really nice but can't beat
>   **Sublime** :)

Well, you can give a try to make "**Your Favorite Sublime Key 'CTRL+SHIFT+L'**" within **ATOM** to get Multi Line Selection with multi cursor:

> **File > Keymap...**

Paste below code and smile :)

```
'atom-text-editor':
    'ctrl-shift-l': 'editor:split-selections-into-lines'
```

Save and Close Tab. Open any file and Press "`CTRL+SHIFT+L`". Now magic :D, Press Arrow key and You will see Multiple Cusor on Selected Lines.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, couldn't set it from the settings panel, and the shorcut key was associated with selecting the programming language for the current file

Answer (score 15):

For Ubuntu you can use `shift-alt-up/down`

Answer (score 7):

For Windows users,
the default keybindings <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Up/Down</kbd> seems to work.

For Mac users,
add the following custom keybinding code to the
`/user/<yourName>/.atom/keymap.cson` file

```
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# change the keybinding for ADD SELECTION ABOVE / BELOW
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#  'shift-alt-up': 'editor:add-selection-above'
#  'shift-alt-down': 'editor:add-selection`-below'
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Then place the cursor where you want to start and press and hold <kbd>Shift+Alt</kbd> and press <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> repeatedly to extend the cursor to as many lines as needed.

+1 to @Lee's solution above. This is same as option 2 above but using keybindings

Comment: For Mac users the keyboard shortcut is the same (`ctrl + shift + up / down`), but those shortcuts also launch Mission Control.  If you want to remove the Mission Control shortcut, just change or deselect it in Keyboards System Preference.

Comment: Yes, @TristanReid, you are correct. If one were to remove the Mission Control shortcuts from the Keyboard System Preference, they don't need to add the above code and simply use the default keybindings.

Comment: for linux users shift+alt+down/up seems to be the default.

Answer (score 6):

This package will let you select multiple lines by holding down "alt" key
https://atom.io/packages/sublime-style-column-selection

Answer (score 3):

And it's ALT + SHIFT + UP/DOWN arrows on Arch (manjaro/i3).

Answer (score 3):

Came here because it's 2019 and I'm still a big fan of atom. 
`CTRL + ALT + Left Click` on each line you want to edit works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I was searching a way to highlight and show the cursor on every line in Atom editor.

> Atom has a pattern match selection. Say like you want to highlight and
>   select a pattern `_`(underscore) in every line:

1. Select a first occurrence of the pattern
2. Then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (In Windows).

Atom editor will run through all the lines and highlight the same pattern.

**BUT** if you want to select and highlight a cursor on every line **without any pattern.**

You can try this shortkey <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>UP/DOWN</kbd>

My Atom editor version is `1.22.1`

Hope this might help.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for multi-line selection and multilines to single line conversion packages and found these wonderful packages.

- Multiline selection package by Bigfile:
  [sublime-style-column-selection](https://atom.io/packages/sublime-style-column-selection)
- Multi lines to single line: [one-liner](https://atom.io/packages/one-liner)